# Matrices and Vectors finding constant k

Tags: matrices, vectors

How to work this problem.

Let Π1, Π2 and Π3 be the planes with Cartesian equations  + 2 + 3 = 5,  −  + 2 = 7 and 3 − 3 + 9 = 10 respectively, where  is a constant. (i) Find  given that Π1, Π2 and Π3 do not have a unique point of intersection.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

With $$x=5-3z-2y$$ we can eliminate $x$, we get
$$13y+6z=-5$$
and
$$z(2-3k)-y(2k+1)=7-15k$$
now with $$z=-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{13}{6}y$$
we get
$$(-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{13}{6}y)(2-3k)-y(2k+1)=7-13k$$
now consider this equation and solve it for $y$ depending on $k$

Comment: can you explain more